# Кратные цифры в input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Надо чтобы в input можно было ввести только цифры кратные 50, например: 50, 100, 150. И чтобы когда пользователь вводил число не кратное число оно без перезагрузки страницы поменялось на ближайшее кратное значение. Как сделать на js или jquery?

Comment: надо сделать дак сделайте. если в процессе возникнут сложности, то опишите их.  а то ограничить значения инпута можно и просто с помощью `pattern="\d+00|\d*50"`

Comment: А ВП тут каким боком?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте аттрибут step для поля nubmer:

```
<input type="number" step="50" min="0">
```

Comment: Пробовал, но цифры не будут округлятся если их ввести с клавиатуры